# Appcenter codepush is returning "The request is blocked"

Tags: react-native, code-push, appcenter

I am running codepush with react native, I was able to upload v1.0 on appcenter, But now when I am running codepush again it is returing "The request is blocked"

My command

```
appcenter codepush release-react -a username/appname -d Staging
```

Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'/><style type='text/css'>body { font-family:Arial; margin-left:40px; }img  { border:0 none; }#content { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto }#message h2 { font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; margin: 34px 0px 0px 0px }#message p  { font-size: 13px; color: #000000; margin: 7px 0px 0px 0px }#errorref { font-size: 11px; color: #737373; margin-top: 41px }</style><title>Microsoft</title></head><body><div id='content'><div id='message'><h2>The request is blocked.</h2></div><div id='errorref'><span>0mvk1ZAAAAABL3Dcb9k3wTb6Z3Cx9Ni2/TUFBMDFFREdFMTYwOABmZGMzYmE0Ny0zODk2LTQyNjAtYjFlNC02MDJmM2I2YzQwYmI=</span></div></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an app center issue.
Please refer to this page
https://status.appcenter.ms/

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be fixed 2 hours ago. I can now push my releases. Check status at https://status.appcenter.ms/.